# Define constant for one plugin in mu-plugin

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, constants, mu-plugins

I'm trying to define the constant `ACF_Lite` as `true` so that the interface of the Advanced Custom Fields plugin is hidden on all of my multisite subsites except the parent. For clarity and maintainability, I'm wanting to do this from an `mu-plugins` plugin that will also control the fields displayed by that plugin.

I thought this would do it but it didn't:

```
if( get_current_blog_id() !== 1 )
    define( 'ACF_Lite', true );
```

The plugin author says that this needs to be in `wp-config.php`, but I'm surprised that this doesn't work because, [according to the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins), mu-plugins are:

> Loaded by PHP, in alphabetical order, before normal plugins,

I've confirmed that `get_current_blog_id()` returns the right ID, so that's not the problem. I've also tried explicitly hooking that to `muplugins_loaded` and `plugins_loaded` but that has failed.

Can anyone explain why I can't define this from `mu-plugins`?

Comment: Put `var_dump(defined('ACF_Lite'))` in your mu-plugin. Is it already defined?

Comment: Should not be defined before the plugin is loaded, see [source](https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf/blob/master/acf.php)

Comment: The answer below solved my issue, but I want to make sure I understand @toscho's comment (upvote and all!). It seems to me that the whole point is to define the constant *before* the plugin is loaded so it doesn't display the UI.

Comment: @mrwweb I just pointed out the _order_ was correct, didn’t see the lower case. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@toscho's link solved this. [PHP constants are case sensitive.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

[ACF uses `ACF_LITE`](https://github.com/elliotcondon/acf/blob/master/acf.php#L15), you are using `ACF_Lite`.